# Unrecognized tag 'x:Members' in namespace

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I am working on the TFS build on Visual Studio 2012. I have written the build template apprx. 2 years ago. till last year it used to work fine.

Now When I try to build the template I get following error.

Unrecognized tag 'x:Members' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'. Note that tag names are case sensitive. Line 45 Position 4.

I went through this blog
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2012/07/17/tfs-2012-cleaning-up-workflow-xaml-files-aka-removing-versioned-namespaces.aspx.
Template have passed the XAMLCleaner as well.

I don't know what went wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check if it is the same with this issue: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2232fe98-d98f-456f-9a97-09efc29d9d58/unrecognized-tag-xmembers-in-namespace?forum=wfprerelease

Comment: Thanks Eddie. Modifying the build action to "XamlAppDef" didn't work for me.  but I set it to Content and its working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Modify the build action to Content.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a WF xaml file, please modify the Build Action (in the properties tool window) to 'XamlAppDef', not 'Page'.